# Call servlet from Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a controller class with `@ResponseBody` annotation to server ajax request.

My requirement is to redirect to a servlet(post method) if a check fails. If check does not fails then i need to respond back with Json data

```
Class Controller {

@ResponseBody redirectTest() {

 if(true) {
    //send json data
} else {
 //Redirect to a servlet
}
```

}

1. Is there a possible way to redirect to post method of servlet.
2. Is there any way to initialize the servlet on need basic, without creating any servlet mapping in web.xml.

Comment: What type of request does this method respond to, post or get?  If post, then it can *forward* to another servlet that responds to post.  If get, then no.

Comment: Indeed it is a post request for this controller

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possible way to redirect to post method of servlet.

Use the [forward prefix](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-forward-prefix)

```
@ResponseBody
public String redirectTest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (true) {
        //send json data
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("someObj", someObj);
        return "forward:/someServlet";
    }
}
```

---

> Is there any way to initialize the servlet on need basic, without creating any servlet mapping in web.xml.

For Servlet 3.0 or above, use the [@WebServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation